# How to test another theme in a live WordPress website instead of live preview?

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme

I want to implement a new theme called Hepta on my current website, but when I test it using the live preview, it shows me limited content and features as it imports most of the contents from the active theme. Hence, I added few core plugins for that theme and also added theme import plugin. But, my concern is that if I activate the theme import plugin, the theme which is currently live(the older theme) might be affected, which will end up affecting the live website. So, I want to test the new theme and make it my primary theme once it is ready. How should I do this?

Comment: So I believe that this is possible with [Health Check](https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/) plugin. I tried to test it now, however, and it malfunctioned. But maybe it was an isolated issue. Still, really the best way to do this is by creating a staging environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To try new theme over live wordpress site you need to duplicate the site in staging. There are many ways to do that:

- Manually: create a sub-domain (ex: staging.domain.com) copy files and DB there and do your changes there after tested well migrate them to live.
- Using plugin: A plugin named [WP-Staging](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-staging/) may help you the manual process.
- You can use [wp-engine](https://wpengine.com/) service, which help you manage staging things.

Hope one of the above way be helpful for you. A help [link](https://themeisle.com/blog/wordpress-staging-site/) to check.